# Android- Create headers for recylcerview which works as a table

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm building an app which shows football league tables. For the table data itself (each team in the table), i use a card view (inside the recylcer view), and everything is looking well. But the problem is that i have no idea how to set headers for this table, which will be exactly on top of the correct team information.
Example - one of the headers is "Team Name", and the team name for the first card view is "Manchester United", so the question is how do i make sure, that the header "Team Name" will be right on top of "Manchester United", no matter the font size or screen size?

Thanks! 
Code:

Adapter and ViewHolder:

```
     public class TeamAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<TeamAdapter.TeamViewHolder> {


private TeamLeagueStandings[] teams;

public TeamAdapter(TeamLeagueStandings[] teams) {
    this.teams = teams;
}

@Override
public TeamAdapter.TeamViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.trycardview, parent, false);

    return new TeamViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TeamAdapter.TeamViewHolder holder, int 
position) {


    TeamLeagueStandings team = teams[position];
    holder.place.setText(team.getPlace());
    holder.teamname.setText(team.getTeamName());
    holder.matches.setText(team.getCurGames());
    holder.wins.setText(team.getWins());
    holder.draws.setText(team.getDraws());
    holder.losses.setText(team.getLosses());
    holder.gd.setText(team.getGoalDifference());
    holder.points.setText(team.getPoints());
    if(Integer.parseInt(team.getPlace()) %2 == 0 )
        holder.rootview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EBEBEB"));
    else
        holder.rootview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return teams.length;

}

public static class TeamViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView place;
    protected TextView teamname;
    protected TextView matches;
    protected TextView wins;
    protected TextView draws;
    protected TextView losses;
    protected TextView gd;
    protected TextView points;
    protected ConstraintLayout rootview;

    public TeamViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        rootview=itemView.findViewById(R.id.rootview);
        place = itemView.findViewById(R.id.position_txtview);
        teamname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.teamName_txtview);
        matches = itemView.findViewById(R.id.matches_txtview);
        wins = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wins_txtview);
        draws = itemView.findViewById(R.id.draws_txtview);
        losses = itemView.findViewById(R.id.losses_txtview);
        gd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gd_txtview);
        points = itemView.findViewById(R.id.points_txtview);
        }
    }
}





//CardView layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/rootview">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/position_txtview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="pos"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
       <!-- app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" -->


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teamName_txtview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Team"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/position_txtview"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/position_txtview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/losses_txtview"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="L"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/position_txtview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/gd_txtview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/draws_txtview"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="D"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/position_txtview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/losses_txtview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wins_txtview"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="W"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/position_txtview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/draws_txtview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/matches_txtview"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="P"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/position_txtview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/wins_txtview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gd_txtview"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="GD"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/position_txtview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/points_txtview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/points_txtview"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="PO"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/position_txtview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```